# RESTful service not returning expected XML

Tags: xml, wcf, rest, response

I have a WCF Rest Service that currently returns an xml response as shown below.

[image: xml response]

However, it should be returned in the following format and I can't get it to output as such.  Any help to get the correct output would be appreciated.

```
<app:get-order-details-response xmlns:apps="http://app.com/123/abc/">
    <organisation-id>123</organisation-id>
    <app2app-id>Mer001</app2app-id>
    <order-id>100</order-id>
    <order-price>0</order-price>
    <response-handler>yourapp://response/parameter1</response-handler>
    <failure-response-handler>yourapp://response/parameter2</failure-response-handler>        
</app:get-order-details-response>
```

The code that generates the current xml is shown below.  Is it because I'm returning an XmlElement?  I've tried returning the XmlDocument and changing the code in the interface to do this, but that doesn't resolve this.

```
public XmlElement GetOrderDetails(string organisationID, string paymentReference, int paymentType, string deviceType)
    {
        .....
        .....
        .....
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("app:get-order-details-response", "http://app.com/123/abc/");
        doc.AppendChild(root);
        CreateElement(doc, root, "organisation-id", organisationID);
        CreateElement(doc, root, "app2app-id", app2appID);
        CreateElement(doc, root, "order-id", paymentReference;
        CreateElement(doc, root, "order-price", paymentAmount);
        CreateElement(doc, root, "response-handler", responseHandler);
        CreateElement(doc, root, "failure-response-handler", failureResponseHandler);

        return root;
    }
```

Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPaymentService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, 
        Method = "GET",
        UriTemplate = "/getorderdetails/v1/aa/order/{organisationID}/{paymentReference}?paymentType={paymentType}&deviceType={deviceType}")]
    XmlElement GetOrderDetails(string organisationID, string paymentReference, int paymentType, string deviceType);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

After making the modification that Pankaj suggested below, the output appears as it should be in IE. However, when testing this against a test toolkit, I get an error message, saying "Cannot find the declaration of element 'app:get-order-details-response'. What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped
```

to

```
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest

OR

BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare
```

Comment: Thanks. The modification at the top appears to work when viewing the output in IE. However, when testing this against a test toolkit, I get an error message, saying "Cannot find the declaration of element 'app:get-order-details-response'. What does this mean?

Comment: It means its not able to find namespace "app" definition. I don't know what tool kit you are using or how it is configured. Probably reconfiguration of your test tool should solve this problem.